# How to update the page while the user is viewing it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, websocket

I have a DB that contain a specific value like `yes`, So if that value is changed by the admin to `no`, If there is a user viewing that page an element would be changed.

So if I have this text in that page and the value is `yes` the text will be:

```
<p id="change">Yes, This text will be changed if the DB value is changed.</p>
```

And if the value is no, The text will be :

```
<p id="change">No, This text will be changed if the DB value is changed.</p>
```

I'm using PHP and MYSQL and can write SQL statements as well as Ajax requests.

I used Ajax many times, But the content was changed for specific visitor or admin, If he did an action.

But I don't know about changing the content of another user, When that DB value is changed.

Comment: One approach here would be to have your JS code periodically poll the database using AJAX to refresh the text on the page.

Comment: So you are talking about running a JS file each specific period of time to check that value?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I don't know the code by heart, by there should be something like a timer which can periodically make an AJAX call.  Note that it is not the responsibility of the database to notify everyone that its data has changed (at least, not typically).

Comment: as you've already tagged, websockets are another option, by which the code running on the webserver can potentially notify the browser of events which occur on the server. Since you already tagged it, it sort of implies you already know about this option...

Comment: @ADyson, Of course I heard of websockets, But I haven't ever used one

Comment: @ADyson, Do you know a PHP websocket and the action or functions that sould be used for that?

Comment: I haven't ever implemented it either, but someone will have. And I can use google. I guess you can too... https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+websocket&oq=php+websocket&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1591j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: For the record, Websockets is _the way to go_ in this case: http://socketo.me/

Comment: Also, That value is changed when the admin clicks a button, If that would help finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX to check the database every x seconds and update the result accordingly.

Using AJAX send a GET or POST request to a path of your site which will return either yes or no after querying the database, and with that result you can use JS to update the content of the `p` element.

I recommend using memcache or similar database cache as querying the database directly every few seconds is not efficient and can degrade your servers performance if many clients are connected on it at the same time.

Ajax Request Frontend GET request

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/backendprocessor.php?id_of_value=1",
        type: "get",
        success: function (response) {
               //check the response and update the element            

        }
    });
```

and for backendprocessor.php, get the id_of_value from $_GET variable and then query the database / cache server and return either YES or NO

So to run the code every 15 seconds you can do this in jQuery,

```
setInterval(getUpdate, 15000);
```

and the getUpdate function will contain the ajax code.

Answer (score 1):

Client side, in your case is the browser, must know the dB value change. There are two ways

1. Client side periodically (maybe every X seconds) sends ajax request to server to check for DB value , if changed, update UI. There will be delay of X seconds. There may also be wasting resources if db value is not changed frequently.

   var getDbValue = function () {

   ```
   $.get("server.php", function(data, status){
       //update the UI
       setTimeout(getDbValue, 5000);
   });
   ```

   };

   setTimeout(getDbValue, 5000);
2. MQTT over websocket. Client subscribes to a message queue topic and server will publish message to the topic  when there is a value update. Client will receive the update in near real-time.

This is a big topic and will require more sever setup. There are also cloud message queue service such as AmazomMQ. It's quite easy to configure if you understand the concept.

```
var client = new MQTTClient(options);

client.connect(options);
client.on('connected', function(){
    client.subscribe("your_topic");
  });
client.on('messageArrived', function(msg){
    //the message will contain the db value published from the server
    //update UI
});
```

Comment: The value in the DB is changed when the admin clicks a button, If that could help

Comment: @Simon for method 1, it doesn't care who changes the value, as long as value it changed. For method 2, as long as the php  can publish a message to the topic when admin clicks the button

Comment: Have you ever used a websocket for a similar purpose?

Comment: @Simon yes, but my use case is more complicated than this. It is similar to online chat room and it will show user online offline in real-time and the moderator will publish real-time announcement to every participant.

Comment: Could you provide me with the way to change an element within a page from another?

Comment: @Simon I have added some sample code. The flow is not changing the element within a page from another. The element is still managed by its own page. The other page will send the instruction to let the page update.